# Generate correlated multivariate normal samples with copula

Tags: correlation, random-generation, copula, random-matrix

I've seen examples of constructing multivariate distribution with univariate marginals coupled together via a normal copula (see  [Mvdc](http://cran.cermin.lipi.go.id/web/packages/copula/copula.pdf)  function from `copula` package in R). However I was wondering whether I could simulate density with multivariate marginals via a normal copula?

---

Just to clarify how I attempted to solve this problem without copula:

Suppose $vec(X_i^T) \sim N_{n \times p} (0, \Sigma_i \otimes I_p ), \, i = 1, \dots, 3$, and $\Psi ( 3x3)$ is the design covariance matrix for the samples. Let L be a $3\times 3$ matrix such that $L L^T = \Psi$, then $Y = X L $, where $X = (vec(X_1^T) \cdots vec(X_3^T))$ would be the desired correlated sample.

However my concern is that this implies $Y$ follows $N_{np,3} (0, V, \Psi)$, where $V$ is the common row covariance matrix. This contradicts with my original setup.

Am I wrong about this?

Comment: I find 'multivariate marginals' somewhat ambiguous here. Could you be considerably more precise about what you're asking for? Could you also explain how the random-matrix tag is particularly relevant?

Comment: @Glen_b My current goal is to generate three random Matrices from matrix normal distributions with zero mean and different covariance structures, also adding correlation between those three. I translate this problem into multivariate cases by vectorising the matrices. Normally for generating correlated samples I would simply multiply the samples by the desired covariance structure but I'm not sure whether I could do this here?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you mean by 'multiply the samples by the desired covariance structure'? -- if I take that literally, it seems to be wrong.

Comment: I meant the lower triangular matrix from the chol decomp of the design covariance, but i don't think it would work for this case as three vectors all have different covariances. I thought I could try copula...

Comment: OKay, the use of the cholesky makes sense. I'm still not sure I am clear on what you're doing here, but if you can stack them up it seems to me you can use the same process as before.